# Add two numbers using Javascript on onload event

Tags: javascript, php, html, textbox

How can i add two numbers from text box when the page loads? it only works when i try to create a button for adding.

```js
function sum() {
  var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('totalprice').value;
  var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('price1').value;
  var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) * parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
  if (!isNaN(result)) {
    document.getElementById('totalprices').value = result;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you run this when the page loads, how will the user enter numbers into the inputs?

Answer (score 1):

use  **window.onload**

```
<script>
  function sum() {
            var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('totalprice').value;
            var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('price1').value;
            var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) * parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
            if (!isNaN(result)) {
                document.getElementById('totalprices').value = result;
            }
        }
  window.onload=sum;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You either need to call the function when your document has finished loading with the `window.onload` listener https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

i.e.

```
function sum(){
     var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('totalprice').value;
            var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('price1').value;
            var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) * parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
            if (!isNaN(result)) {
                document.getElementById('totalprices').value = result;
            }
        }
window.onload = sum;
```

Alternatively, you can run the code after the HTML in the document and without it being in a function and then it will interpret immediately

e.g.

```
<html>

<div>some stuff here</div>
... // bottom of document
<script>
var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('totalprice').value;
                var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('price1').value;
                var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) * parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
                if (!isNaN(result)) {
                    document.getElementById('totalprices').value = result;
                }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer jQuery over regular Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var txtFirstNumberValue = $('#totalprice').val();
    var txtSecondNumberValue = $('#price1').val();
    var result = (parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) * parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue));
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
        $('#totalprices').val(result);
    }
});
```

This will also fire sooner than a `window.onload`, resulting in a better user experience.